# How to retrieve the first object for each set of values in a django filter operation?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, query-optimization

I'm running a django 1.29 app on a postgresql database. I have a model similar to this:

```py
class DataFile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('data.User', verbose_name='Data View')
    period = models.ForeignKey('data.Period', verbose_name='Period')
    category = models.ForeignKey('data.Period', verbose_name='Period')
    
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
```

My code is currently retrieving objects that the program needs as this:

```py
pending_ids = pending_files.values_list("id", flat=True).distinct()
my_data = pending_files.values_list("user_id","category_id","period_id")

import_files_pending=[]

for u, c, p in pending_bu_way_period:
    last_file_bpw = DataFile.objects.filter(user_id=u, period_id=p,category_id=c).order_by('-created').first()
    if last_file_bpw and last_file_bpw.id in pending_ids:
        import_files_pending.append(last_file_bpw)
```

But is very inefficent, so I tried refractoring and came up with this:

```py
import_files_pending2 = DataFile.objects.filter(id__in=pending_ids,user_id=my_data.values_list("user_id", flat=True),
                                            category_id__in=my_data.values_list("category_id", flat=True),
                                            period_id__in=my_data.values_list("period_id", flat=True)).order_by('user_id',
                                                                                                          'period_id',
                                                                                                         '-created').distinct("from_who_id",
                                                                                                                                   'period_id')
```

But it appears to retrieve much more objects other than the ones I need.
What am I doing wrong? Why is my refractoring giving different results?
For what I understand, my query is not retrieving only the first instance for the other values' combination, but any of them.

Comment: Yes, since if `user_id__in=[1,2]` and `category_id__in=[3,4]`, it will not retrieve one with `user_id=1` and `category_id=3` and another one with `user_id=2` and `category_id=4`, but it can retrieve a total of four items, each possible combination.

Comment: What is `pending_files`?

Comment: It's also a queryset of DataFiles

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that if you check for membership, i.e.:

```
DataFile.objects.filter(user_id__in=[1, 2], category_id__in=[3, 4])
```

can produce up to four different configurations. Indeed, it will not only return `DataFile`s with `user_id=1` and `category_id=3`; and then `user_id=2` and `category_id=4`, it can also return items with `user_id=2` and `category_id=3` for example.

It thus works as a "*cartesian product*", not as a "zip". But likely you don't need to work with `__in` checks anyway, you can just use the `pending_files`:

```
pending_files.order_by('user_id', 'period_id', 'category_id' '-created').distinct(
    'user_id', 'period_id', 'category_id'
)
```

and that is likely all we need. Indeed, `pending_files` seems to be already a queryset of `DataFile`s, so we can just modify this into the desired one.